# Where should i use 3rd party API in my fullstack Nest.JS + Nuxt App

Tags: api, vue.js, architecture, nuxt.js, nestjs

I am a novice developer and I am wondering about a certain thing.
As a side project, I am currently creating an application in Nest.JS and Nuxt 3 technology.
The application will include a search engine using 3rd party open API.
Should the queries be executed directly on the frontend, or should my backend server be a sort of middleman?

API that  will be using: https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_API

Comment: You can directly call third party API from Nuxt. I don’t think you’ll require Nest as middle man. For your applications API, Nest will be used

Comment: Usually, it depends of the API. Some are client based, other can reach a database of some sort (Redis, Elasticsearch etc...).